# Can Gandalf magically manipulate smoke rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In the Lord of the Rings movie, Gandalf is shown manipulating smoke rings in a clearly magical way.

Is there any evidence in the books that he can do this?

I recall he blew smoke rings in LOTR but don’t recall anything unexplainable by skill.

Comment: It's described more in" The Hobbit"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *The Hobbit* Gandalf shows the ability to use magic to manipulate the shape, speed, direction and colour of his rings.

> Gandalf would not hear of it. So they spread out their wet things on
> the floor, and got dry ones out of their bundles; then they made their
> blankets comfortable, got out their pipes and blew smoke rings, which
> Gandalf turned into different colours and set dancing up by the roof
> to amuse them.
>
> <sub><sup>The Hobbit - Chapter 7</sup></sub>

and

> This is a splendid place for smoke rings!" Indeed for a long time they could get nothing more out of him, he was so busy sending smoke-rings dodging round the pillars of the hall, changing them into all sorts of different shapes and colours, and setting them at last chasing one another out of the hole in the roof. They must have looked very queer from outside, popping out into the air one after another, green, blue, red, silver-grey, yellow, white; big ones, little ones; little ones dodging through big ones and joining into figure-eights, and going off like a flock of birds into the distance.

and

> Then they went back, and found Thorin with his feet on the fender
> smoking a pipe. He was blowing the most enormous smoke-rings, and
> wherever he told one to go, it went-up the chimney, or behind the
> clock on the man-telpiece, or under the table, or round and round the
> ceiling; but wherever it went it was not quick enough to escape
> Gandalf. Pop! he sent a smaller smoke-ring from his short clay-pipe
> straight through each one of Thorin's. The Gandalf's smoke-ring would
> go green and come back to hover over the wizard's head. He had quite a
> cloud of them about him already, and in the dim light it made him look
> strange and sorcerous.

There's no indication. however, that he can make them into pictures or three-dimensional objects

Comment: Is this the only instance shown of Thorin having magic? Or at least tele-kinesis?

Comment: @FlaStorm32 - That sounds like it's worth asking as a question